# How to implement multi keyword search in C?

Tags: c, performance, search

I want to implement a case-insensitive text search which supports parallel testing of multiple keywords. I was already able to achieve this in a way which to me does not seem to be efficient in terms of performance.

The function "strcasestr" ([Link to Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasestr)) seems to be doing a good job when searching for one keyword, but when you want to simultaneously test multiple keywords - in my understanding - you want to iterate the characters of the text (Haystack) only one single time to find an occurrence of the keywords (Needles).

Using "strcasestr" multiple times would cause - how I understand it - multiple iterations over the text (Haystack), which might not be the fastest solution. An example:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

  // Text to search in
  char *str = "This is a test!";

  char *result = strcasestr(str, "not_found1");

  if (result == NULL) {
    result = strcasestr(str, "NOT_FOUND2");
  }

  if (result == NULL) {
    result = strcasestr(str, "TEST!");
  }

  printf("Result pointer: %s\n", result );

  return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to get the position of the first occurrence of one of the (case-insensitive) keywords in the text in a faster way than I did it?

I would appreciate it if the solution would be extensible so that I could continue looping over the text to find **all** positions of the occurrences of the keywords, because I am working on a full-text search with a result rating system. Frameworks and small hints to put me in the right direction are also very welcome.

Comment: I implemented a multiple keyword search in text files, targeted at a potentially large number of files. Because I have an option to search on partial words, or a phrase, or span more than one word, I found it convenient to search a file once for each keyword. I also implemented AND and OR options. In either case a search for a single keyword is usually all that is needed to either eliminate (AND) or accept (OR) from a single keyword search, and the search of subsequent keywords is not usually necessary. In your case, having found a matching file, you could then examine it for a full analysis.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm

Comment: One way is to use threads and implement strcasestr() locally with search data like array index access through mutex

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of learning and testing I found a solution which is working well for me. I tested a one-keyword version of it and the performance was comparable to the function "strcasestr" (Tested with ca. 500 MB of text).

To explain what the below code does:

First the text (Haystack) and the keywords (Needles) are defined. Then the keywords are already converted into lowercase for good performance. **iter** is an Array of numbers which reflect how many characters the current text progress  is in match with each keyword. The program linearly iterates over each character of **text** until it finds a match in one of the keywords - in this case, the program ends and the result is "True". If it does not find a match (=0), the result if "False".

I welcome tips in the comments for better code quality or higher performance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void) {

  int i, j;
  int match = 0;

  // Haystack
  char *text = "This is a test!";

  // Needles
  int keywords_len = 3;
  char keywords[][12] = {
    "not_found1",
    "NOT_FOUND2",
    "TEST!"
  };

  // Make needles lowercase
  for (i = 0; i < keywords_len; i++)
    for (j = 0; keywords[i][j]; j++)
      keywords[i][j] = tolower(keywords[i][j]);

  // Define counters for keywords matches
  int iter[] = { 0, 0, 0 };

  // Loop over all characters and test match
  char ptext;
  while (ptext = *text++)
    // Compare matches
    // NOTE: (x | 32) means case-insensitive
    if (!match)
      for (i = 0; i < keywords_len; i++)
        if ((ptext | 32) == keywords[i][iter[i]]) {
          if (keywords[i][++(iter[i])] == '\0') {
            match = 1;
            break;
          }
        } else
          iter[i] = 0;
    else
      break;

  printf("Result: %s\n", match ? "True" : "False");

  return 0;
}
```